# When returning a reference to an object from C++, is it necessary to use the "&" operator in the return variable?

Tags: c++

Say I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Account
{
private:
    float balance;

public:
    Account() { balance = 0.0; };
    float GetBalance() { return balance; };
    void SetBalance(float newBalance) { balance = newBalance; };
};

Account mainAccount;

Account& GetAccount()
{
    return mainAccount;
}

void PrintAccountInfo()
{
    cout << "mainAccount's balance is " << mainAccount.GetBalance() << endl;
}

int main()
{
    PrintAccountInfo();
    Account &a = GetAccount(); // Line 31
    a.SetBalance(30.0);
    PrintAccountInfo();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I get the following output (as expected):

```
mainAccount's balance is 0
mainAccount's balance is 30
```

However, on line 31, if I take out the "&" in the "Account &a", to make it this:

```
Account a = GetAccount(); // note lack of "&"
```

I get this output:

```
mainAccount's balance is 0
mainAccount's balance is 0
```

How come? I thought when returning a reference, the "&" is redundant / not necessary? Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how references work in C++?

EDIT: Thanks, I understand now why the two are different. However, then shouldn't I be able to do this:

```
Account GetAccount()
{
    return mainAccount;
}

int main()
{
    Account &a = GetAccount();
    // ....
}
```

However, when I run that, I get an error:

> untitled: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> untitled:31: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Account&’ from a temporary of type ‘Account’

Comment: In one, you're copying the returned variable into a new one. In the other, you're initializing a reference with the returned variable.

Comment: "I thought when returning a reference, the "&" is redundant" To the contrary, you return a reference *by* using "&". Otherwise you return a value (which will be a copy of what was returned).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I thought when returning a reference, the "&" is redundant / not necessary?*

You thought wrong.

Consider these two different lines:

```
Account &a = GetAccount(); // Line 31

Account a = GetAccount(); // Line 31
```

In the first, you declare a reference called `a` which is bound to the object returned by the function `GetAccount`.

In the second, you declare an object `a` which is copy-initialized by the object returned by the function `GetAccount`.

Fundamentally: one declares a reference, the other declares an object.

---

**EDIT**: Answering the follow-on question:

> "*can I remove the `&` from the return type in the declaration of the `GetAccount` function: `Account GetAccount() { return mainAccount; }`*"

You certainly *can* remove the `&`, but then your behavior will change. Consider these two functions:

```
Account GetAccount() { return mainAccount; }

Account &GetAccount() { return mainAccount; }
```

In the first, you return a temporary object which has been copy-initialized from the `mainAccount` object. In the second you return a reference to the `mainAccount` object.

- If you want `a` to be a reference to `mainAccount`, you need `&` in both places.
- If you want `a` to be a copy of `mainAccount`, you need no `&` in the declaration of `a`. The other declaration won't matter *in this case*.
- If you want `a` to be a reference to a compiler-generated temporary value (hint: you don't), declare `a` with `&`, but `GetAccount` without.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, can I remove the `&` from the return type in the declaration of the `GetAccount` function:

Account GetAccount() { return mainAccount; }

Comment: Yes, you can, but you'll get a different program. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You return a reference, but you then create a new object using that reference. `a` is the new object that gets copy-initialized using the reference returned from `GetAccount`.

Remember, a reference is an alias. It's like saying:

```
int x = 0;
int& y = x;

int z = y;
//is equivalent to
z = x;
```

`z` doesn't refer to `x` nor `y` in this case, because `z` itself isn't a reference.

So:

```
x = 1;
```

would modify both `x` and `y`, but `z` would still be 0.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases you return a reference, but there is a difference in how you use it:

```
Account &a = GetAccount();
```

In this case you use the reference to initialize another reference, making `a` a reference to the original Data.

```
Account a = GetAccount();
```

In this case you use your returned reference to initialize an object of type `Account`, instead of a reference to Account. Therefore you **copy** the original object into the newly created `a`.

Answer (score 0):

It does matter.

This version

```
Account a = GetAccount(); // note lack of "&"
```

creates a *copy* of the account, not a reference. Therefore when changing the balance, you change the balance of the copy, not the original.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question from the title: Not directly.

```
typedef Account& AccountRef; // Hiding here
AccountRef GetAccount()
{
    return mainAccount;
}
```

BTW, `&` isn't used as an operator here. It modifies the `Account` type. It can be used as an unary and binary operator, e.g. in `&obj` or `5 & 6`. When used as an operator, it must appear before or between expressions.